# MATLAB Memory Management of Matrix Column/Row-Deletion

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory

I have an array of size 5x4 in MATLAB.

```
A = [ 1  2  3  4
      5  6  7  8
      9 10 11 12
     13 14 15 16
     17 18 19 20];
```

Since MATLAB stores arrays in column-wise fashion, `A` will be in memory in the following order

```
A = 1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20
```

My question is what happens when I delete the last two columns/rows of `A`:

```
A(:,3:4) = [];
```

or

```
A(4:5,:) = [];
```

Will MATLAB create (copy) a new array in a different part of the memory and assigns the new address to `A` again or `A` will still be in the same memory location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will MATLAB create (copy) a new array in a different part of the memory and assigns the new address to A again?

I'd say the answer is: probably, and it certainly may, but whether it actually does is not necessarily specified by the language documentation (at least not that I've seen).

Generally, because Matlab is a pass-by-value, copy-on-write language, *any* modification to the data inside an array can cause it to be reallocated and copied, because any other existing references to that array need to retain the old value. "In-place" modifications are just an optimization used in certain cases where Matlab can determine that an array value is contained within a local scope/workspace. So if there are any other references to that array held in `A`, then the memory will definitely be reallocated and copied.

But if your `A` array value was limited to that single reference, Matlab *could* in theory keep the same allocated memory for the array's underlying values, and just shuffle them around within that same block of memory, leaving some of it unused at the end. I doubt that it would actually do so, because that would waste memory, with no definite point where it would be reclaimed in the future.

As a practical matter, I would assume that it always does get copied to a newly allocated block of memory.

You could test a particular version of Matlab to see whether it does so in your case by checking the pointer addresses returned by `mxGetData` in the MEX API before and after the modification, or looking at memory allocation in the profiler.